# Caption area div not centre aligned inside header div

Tags: css, html

I have a header div, and inside this I have a caption div. I'm trying to centre align the caption div. Currently the caption div is aligned to the left. I might just be incredibly dim, but i've been looking at code all day, so my mind is fried.

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div class="caption">First Caption - Health & Safety</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#header {
 position:relative;
 width:1200px;
 height:400px;
 margin:auto;
 border:1px solid red;
}

.caption {
 position:absolute;
 width:1000px;
 height:140px;
 background-color: red;
 margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/e4zyh/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pls try to remove the

```
position:absolute;
```

Comment: completely forgot I had set it to absolute. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @PranavCBalan with this :" margin-left: -500px; left:50%; " it's not dynamic , every time you change the with you must change the margin-left

Answer (score 0):

try to add margin-left:value; to caption class.
for exemple margin-left:10%;